# Disable incremental compilation in javac Ant task

Tags: ant, javac, annotation-processing

I need to easily test my annotation processors, so I prepared Ant script to launch `javac` with all the necessary options set. Unfortuantely, as stated in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590579/can-standard-sun-javac-do-incremental-compiling):

> By default the  task compares the timestamps of .java and
>   corresponding .class files, and only tells the Java compiler to
>   recompile source files that are newer than their corresponding object
>   files, or that don't have an object file at all.

It's great for me most of the times but not when I need to test my annotation processor for which I need javac to be launched each time, no matter if corresponding .class file already exist.

Is there any way to disable this ant default behaviour? I looked through all options of `javac` task but found nothing. Is there any solution other then cleaning output directory?

Comment: I do it with cleaning the output directory everytime, can't think of any other option right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your quote if you delete the .class files, the compiler will be forced to recompile the .java file

Comment: Thank you, It seems that there is really no other option than this.